# How to give duplicated model/rig different textures than the original?

Tags: texturing

Let me start by saying I know very little about Blender; I am an artist using Blender to photograph references for myself. I recently purchased a rigged dog model and I've had no issues learning posing, lighting, rendering, coloring textures and such through tutorials on YouTube but I am having trouble figuring out how to duplicate the model without having it share the same textures as the original. I am trying to color the second dog black and have the first dog remain white to represent two different characters in the scene.

I duplicated the collection and was able to pose the second model independently from the other and render them in the same scene, but I can't figure out how to give it separate textures to save my life.

Answer (score 0):

In the material slots there is a number displaying the users of that material (in your scene probably it's 2).

If you click on that number the material is duplicated, and it can be independently edited.

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you!